# Is there a way to loop through pages using selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am gathering listing information from Craigslist and I am able to get all of the listings on the first page, save as .csv file, and export to my MongoDB collection. I would like to know how to go to the next page of the website after all of the listings are collected on the first page, then get all of that's pages listings and so on until the script gets all of the listings on the last page and there are no more pages left.

I noticed that by default, Craigslist shows 119 listings on the first page, then page two shows listings 121->240 and so on. the format on the website is "1-120/#num of total listings". also the URL has an element "s=" that updates every time you click "next page" and go the new page. Example, on the first page "s=" is not in URL so I put "s=0" in its place and the page loaded up normally. Go to next page and "s=120", next page "s=240", and so on.

I was thinking about getting the total number of listings after the search(n) and setting MAX_PAGES = 119/n (round up). Then in the init main, put a for loop  "for I in range(MAX_PAGES)" around the function that gets the URL and makes sure all of the listings were collected and written to the .csv file.I just do not know how to get #num of total listings from the craigslist page.

***Update***
realized my proposal will just get the contents from the first page again and again. I need a selenium tool to physically go to the next page until idk while next_page != nul.

Craigslist next page button contents while inspecting in chrome

```
<a href="/search/sss?s=120&amp;max_price=700&amp;postal=19132&amp;query=graphics%20card&amp;search_distance=400" class="button next" title="next page">next &gt; </a>
```

constructor

```
def __init__(self, location, postal_code, max_price, query, radius,s):
    self.location = location
    self.postal_code = postal_code
    self.max_price = max_price
    self.query = query
    self.radius = radius
    self.s = s

    # MAX_PAGE_NUM =

    self.url = f"https://{location}.craigslist.org/search/sss?s={s}&max_price={max_price}&postal={postal_code}&query={query}&20card&search_distance={radius}"

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    self.delay = 5
```

gets url

```
def load_craigslist_url(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchform")))
        print("Page is ready")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too long")
```

extracts listings in url

```
 def extract_post_urls(self):
        url_list = []
        html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "result-title hdrlnk"}):
            print(link["href"])
            url_list.append(link["href"])
        return url_list
```

Main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = '/home/diego/git_workspace/PyScrape/data.csv'  # Filepath of written csv file
    location = "philadelphia"  # Location Craigslist searches
    postal_code = "19132"  # Postal code Craigslist uses as a base for 'MILES FROM ZIP'
    max_price = "700"  # Max price Craigslist limits the items too
    query = "graphics+card"  # Type of item you are looking for
    radius = "400"  # Radius from postal code Craigslist limits the search to
    s = 0

    scraper = CraigslistScraper(location, postal_code, max_price, query, radius, s)
    scraper.load_craigslist_url()
    titles, prices, dates = scraper.extract_post_information()
```

What I expect is to get every listing from one page, then go to the next page and gets its listing, and so on until i get all of the listings on the last page and there are no more pages left

Comment: if you use Selenium then simply find button "Next Page" and click it. If you can't find button then you are on last page. This way you don't have to know `MAX_PAGES`

Comment: So, if I get it right, all you are trying to do, is open a page with + 120 ... example: "hello.com/s=0" ~> "hello.com/s=120" ... if I got it right, than all you need to do is just to build a string with x * 120 and increment x everytime the loop ends ... also, talking about that "max", you will just do while True: if something on page s+120

Comment: Just keep following `[rel=next]` - this actually works for most sites.

Comment: @StyleZ How would the loop then know how to stop of I'm incrementing s? I need to know the max num of listings.

Comment: No, because of when you get after spcific s, the website will tell you, that something went wrong ... so then you will know, its where it needs to stop ( mostly it throws 404 )